# LM339 LED voltage indicator behaving opposite of expected

Tags: voltage, comparator

I have built the attached circuit and am pretty confident it is correct with no short circuits. When it's powered up with a 9V battery, all 4 LEDs light up with no input voltage. As the input voltage increases, the LEDs switch off, starting with 1, with 4 going off last.

I've built this circuit before successfully and haven't the foggiest idea what's going on now. It's almost as if it's the wrong chip and doing the opposite job.

[LM339 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm339-n.pdf)

[image: schematic]

---

The wires to the right are to the input voltage. Wires to left and bread board are to change the control resistance.

[image]

---

Close up of picture 1

[image]

---

Rear view of soldering. No shorts despite what it looks like...

By the way, I built this on a bread board previously with the same result, don't know why I expected a different result with this prototype.

[image]

Comment: Check the + and - pin numbers.

Comment: No input voltage sounds like a floating input voltage - try connecting Vin to ground/0 volts

Comment: It is hard to say, but have the LEDs been connected with the right polarity?

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. All the ideas are on build quality i.e. have you actually made what you've drawn? Are the parts faulty? Remove the comparator from it's IC socket or desolder it, test the circuit through with a DMM (on resistance range, not buzz), put in a new comparator... Come back once you've checked everything. It's the fault isn't somewhere you expect, it has to be somewhere you don't expect.

Comment: @Syed, The LEDs could not possibly light up if they were installed as shown in the diagram above but wrong way 'round. The LEDs are connected between the positive power supply rail and the LM339 outputs. The only way in which current could flow in the opposite direction would be if the outputs were somehow driven to a higher voltage than the +Vcc supply. That's not going to happen. In fact, the outputs are open-collector, NPN transistors. The only way current is going to flow is _in_ to the output pin and from there to ground.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, and thanks for the welcome Tony. The parts seem OK, I've checked what I can with a DMM, the resistances check out and I can't identify any short circuits. On my 4th IC, same result with each. CL: Pos (pin 3) and neg (pin 12) checked and OK, no lights under any conditions if reversed. Brhans: pics to follow, please don't laugh... Andy, won't that just short out the input? Syed, yes the LEDs have correct polarity. Thanks again.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Hi, Your "answers" (which wasn't answers to your original question, and therefore should not have been posted in the "Your Answer" box) have been added to the question as edits i.e. updates. Unless you are writing the *full* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself, with no further help needed) please *do not* use the "Your Answer" box below. Instead, you should [edit] the question to add new information. See the [tour] and [help] for more site rules and etiquette. This site is very different from typical internet forums. Thanks.

Comment: The datasheet of the LM339 shows that it has PNP transistors on its inputs then its inputs are high unless they have a resistor to ground them.

Comment: Sounds like your "input voltage" is actually sweeping from max to min. Get a voltmeter out and look at the voltages at the comparator input pins: an LED should be ON (comparator output low) if the '-' input is higher than its '+' input.

Comment: Thanks again for all the replies, you've given me lots to try and I've made some progress. I'll start again and try and get just one of the comparators working on a breadboard.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? When the input is low the corresponding output is low and the LED is on. As the inputs increase it turns on the output and the corresponding LED turns off.